# Difficulty getting stored sharedPreferences valuses from main.dart to use in any screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a shared preferences class containing all shared preferences, and it is been initialized in main.dart

I can access my stored values from a screen if the data is sent through an action - e.g. button tapped. but I can't access the same values when I visit the same screen from another route/screen without the button that has the stored data.

So, I want a situation where I can check if those shared preferences values exist from my main.dart and load them on any screen without having to go through a particular screen.

Below is my code:

```
//SharedPreferences class

    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'dart:core';
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
    
    class SaveInputs {
      static late SharedPreferences _preferences;
    
      static Future init() async {
        _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      }
    
      //the storeList method
      static Future storeComList(List<dynamic> comm) async {
        final List<String> jsonList = comm.map((item) => jsonEncode(item)).toList();
        await _preferences.setStringList('comlist', jsonList);
      }
    
      //getting the stored value of list data
      static List<dynamic>? getComList() {
        final List<String>? jsonList = _preferences.getStringList('comlist');
        final List? comm = jsonList == null
            ? jsonList
            : jsonList.map((item) => jsonDecode(item)).toList();
        return comm;
      }

  //storing verified sellers
  static Future saveVerifiedSeller(bool vseller) async {
    await _preferences.setBool('verified', vseller);
  }

  //getting the stored value of verified sellers
  static bool? fetchVerifiedSeller() => _preferences.getBool('verified');

  //Seller List
  //storing seller list
  static Future storeSellerList(List<dynamic> seller) async {
    final List<String> jsonList =
        seller.map((item) => jsonEncode(item)).toList();
    await _preferences.setStringList('sellist', jsonList);
  }

  //getting the stored value of seller list
  static List<dynamic>? getSellerList() {
    final List<String>? jsonList = _preferences.getStringList('sellist');
    final List? seller = jsonList == null
        ? jsonList
        : jsonList.map((item) => jsonDecode(item)).toList();
    return seller;
  }

}



//Main.dart
//import all importable...

    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
      await SaveInputs.init();
    
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
    
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    
      //These are the three things I want to get from shared preferences class
    
      bool isVerified = false;
      List isListed = [];
      List hasSellers = [];
      
      
      void readData() async {
        setState(() {
          isVerified = (SaveInputs.fetchVerifiedSeller() ?? false);
          isListed = (SaveInputs.getComList() ?? []);
          hasSellers = (SaveInputs.getSellerList() ?? []);
        });
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        readData();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: appName,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: appColor,
          ),
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/': (context) => SplashScreen(),
            '/onboarding': (context) => const Onboarding(),
            '/login': (context) => const LoginForm(),
            '/dashboard': (context) => const Dashboard(),
            '/about_us': (context) => const About(),
            '/commodity': (context) => const Commodity(),
            
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

I can access stored shared preferences if the data is passed via button but I can't see those values when the app loads because it goes from splash screen to the onboarding screen. So I want a situation where as app loads, from main.dart where the routes are, it checks for those stored value that is needed and can be passed unto any of those routes/screens.

Comment: @Loren.A suggested solution worked. I placed the variables directly inside SaveInputs class and the readData in the init() as he said, and then called SaveInputs.isListed, isVerified...etc. from any screen. After running it says null is not a subtype of type ... So I added Future<void> getData1() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (SaveInputs.hasSellers.isEmpty) return;
    List<dynamic>? cjson = _preferences.getStringList('clist');
    //return comm;
  } in those screens where I want to see the data. And it worked

Comment: Good to hear. FYI, typically this comment should go under the answer that is referring to, and marking the answer as accepted let's future readers know that it is the answer that solved your issue at first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest putting those variables in your `SaveInputs` class and initializing them in your `init` function.

```
class SaveInputs {
  static late SharedPreferences _preferences;

  static bool isVerified = false;
  static List isListed = [];
  static List hasSellers = [];

  static Future init() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await _readData();
  }

   static Future<void> _readData() async {
    isVerified = fetchVerifiedSeller() ?? false;
    isListed = getComList() ?? [];
    hasSellers = getSellerList() ?? [];
  }
...
}
```

This way they're fully initialized before `MyApp` is built and if needed you can navigate based on those values without having to initialize them in your `MyApp` widget. And it could then be stateless.

You could pass any of those values to other screens or access them directly from any page with `SaveInputs.isListed` etc...

Comment: Okay, I'm trying this now. Thanks

Comment: suggested solution worked. I placed the variables directly inside SaveInputs class and the readData in the init() as he said, and then called SaveInputs.isListed, isVerified...etc. from any screen. After running it says null is not a subtype of type ... So I added Future<void> getData1() async { _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); if (SaveInputs.hasSellers.isEmpty) return; List<dynamic>? cjson = _preferences.getStringList('clist'); //return comm; } in those screens where I want to see the data. And it worked

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having a problem because initializing shared preferences is async, as in this line:

```
_preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

So what you can do is to make peace with it. In your `readData()` function you can have this line (also create `_preferences` variable in that class).

```
_preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

And then in the `build()` function of `MyApp`, you can have code like:

```
@override Widget build() {

if (_preferences == null) return MaterialApp(
      home: Text('Waiting for preferences to be loaded'));

return MaterialApp(
      home: Text('Preferences is loaded, here is a sample: ${_preferences.getBool('verified')}'));
}
```

This way you will effectively wait for preferences to load before you use it in your `build()` function.

Comment: I do not know how to resolve the double 'returns' after adding this --- if (_preferences == null) return Text('Waiting for preferences to be loaded');

return Text('Preferences is loaded, here is a sample: ${_preferences.getBool('verified')}'); so I did this -- _preferences == (null) ? Text('Waiting for preferences...') : Text('Preferences is loaded, here is a sample: ${_preferences.getBool('verified')}); But I could not still access those values from main.dart

Comment: I also added the _preferences variable and included it in the readData() function. Still the same. void readData() async {
    SharedPreferences _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      newVerified = (_preferences.getBool('verified') ?? false);
      newListed = (_preferences.getStringList('comlist') ?? []);
      newSellers = (_preferences.getStringList('sellist') ?? []);
    });
  }

Comment: There is nothing to resolve there. One of the returns is inside the if, the other one is not.

Comment: SharedPreferences _preferences variable needs to be in the class, not in the function. Just like in your SaveInputs class.

Comment: is there something I need to do in the routes? the values are still not fetched

Comment: You can try updating your answer with your new code

Comment: I've put it the way it was. Still having the same problem

Comment: I understand your problem and I'm trying to help. You should try doing what I said and add the resulting code and output to your question, if you continue with it you will end up with a running app. If you don't I will lose interest and say good luck. Best.

Comment: //imports... 
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await SaveInputs.init();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _preferences;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_preferences == null) return Text('Waiting for preferences to be loaded');

    return Text('Preferences is loaded, here is a sample: ${_preferences.getBool('verified')}');
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false...

Comment: I don't know. May be am putting the if(_preferences... in the wrong place. when I add it, the MaterialApp returns as dead code

Comment: I edited my answer to add the material app so it actually works. you should edit your answer rather than posting code in comments which is extremely hard to read.

Comment: Also give the exact error rather than saying it's the same error

Comment: I mean "edit your question" not "edit your answer".